# Не удается получить значение из DataSet'а

Tags: c#, база-данных, .net, oracle

Есть DataSet, в нем таблица, когда пытаюсь получить значение:

```
_partnerInfo.Surname = partnersDataSet.AI_PARTNERS[0].SURNAME
```

которое Nullable, получаю:
StrongTypingException
"The value for column SURNAME in table AI_PARTNERS is DBNull."

Как можно получить значение? Проверка на null не помогает, так как, чтоб проверить на null, нужно вызвать геттер который мне возращает Exception...

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Проверяйте: `...SURNAME is DBNull`.

Comment: для проверки я должен дернуть этот "SURNAME", тобиш при проверке я получу exception

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, что Вам нужно сделать вот так:

```
partnerInfo.Surname = partnersDataSet.AI_PARTNERS[0].SURNAME == DBNull.Value 
    ? string.Empty // или null
    : partnersDataSet.AI_PARTNERS[0].SURNAME
```

или так:

```
partnerInfo.Surname = DBNull.Value.Equals(partnersDataSet.AI_PARTNERS[0].SURNAME) 
    ? string.Empty // или null
    : partnersDataSet.AI_PARTNERS[0].SURNAME
```

Для ознакомления:

1. [DBNull - класс](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.dbnull(v=vs.110).aspx)
2. [DBNull.Value - поле](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.dbnull.value(v=vs.110).aspx)
3. [Convert.IsDBNull - метод](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.convert.isdbnull(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: тут то и проблема, чтоб сравнить значение мне его нужно получить, геттер который  сгенерирован датаСетом сам делает такую проверку и выкидивает мне исключение, тоесть сравнить значение я не могу, переписивать ДатаСет дизайнер не охотно, слишком много нужно переписать, отлавливать в блоке try/catch думаю плохая идея, так как полей много, заполнять промежуточную таблицу и работать сней, так зачем тогда ДатаСет...

Comment: @user221074, только хотел Вам предложить [DataRow.IsNull](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow.isnull(v=vs.110).aspx), но увидел, что Вы уже разобрались.

Answer (score 0):

В целом, помогли найты решение на stackoverflow.com English.
У меня typed dataset, и решение делать проверку через перезагрузку метода [DataRow.IsNull](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow.isnull(v=vs.110).aspx) делается проверка на null или делать проверку методом yourDataRow.IsFieldnameNull()
в моем случаее
partnersDataSet.AI_PARTNERS[0].IsMIDLENAMENull()

похожие вопросы:[Get cell value from Dataset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39675185/get-cell-value-from-dataset) (typed dataset)
[Problem with typed dataset nullable date value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7161004/problem-with-typed-dataset-nullable-date-value)